# Arranging Prime Factors to form Integer Solutions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem as such:

> How many solutions in positive integers are there to the equation $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_4 = 2^{20} \cdot 13^{13}$? Let $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ all be distinguishable, so $x_1=a,x_2=b,x_3=c,x_4=d$ is distinct from $x_1=d,x_2=c,x_3=b,x_4=a$.

I realized that $2^{20} \cdot 13^{13}$ has a unique prime factorization that is, of course, $2^{20} \cdot 13^{13}$. So all positive integer solutions must be products of these terms. However, I'm pretty stumped as to how to 'arrange' all the $33$ integers to form all possible factors $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for pairs of solutions in nonnegative integers to the following system of equations:
$$ \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 + \alpha_4 = 20$$
$$ \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 + \beta_4 = 13$$
Then you have $x_i=2^{\alpha_i}13^{\beta_i}$.

More details, as requested.  Here's one example: $\alpha_1=18, \alpha_2=0, \alpha_3=0,\alpha_4=2, \beta_1=1, \beta_2=9, \beta_3=2,\beta_4=1$.  This corresponds to $x_1=2^{18}13^1, x_2=2^013^{9}, x_3=2^{0}13^{2}, x_4=2^213^1$.  When we multiply $x_1x_2x_3x_4=2^{18+0+0+2}13^{1+9+2+1}=2^{20}13^{13}$.

These are called [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions), so your final answer is $${23\choose 3}{16\choose 3}=991760$$

Comment: This is not entirely clear to me. Could you please elaborate a little?